# Apache Rewrite Rule (Regex)

Tags: regex, apache, mod-rewrite

I'm using apache and i need to rewrite URL of type:

> /a/b/c/d/boundary/stuff*

to:

> /boundary/a_b_c_d/stuff*

I need to rewrite the first Uri to the second format.

The number of elements before '/boundary' are variable and i want to replace all slashes('/') between elements by '_'

The boundary word is always the same.

I believe i need to do make two rules, one for slash replace and another to change boundary to the beginning of the URL:

The second rule i think is something like  **^/(.*?)/\bboundary\b** to **/boundary/$1**

Is it possible to achieve what i want ?!

How?!

Thank you.

EDIT

I want to match until first boundary word,
it's possible to have a URL like

> /a/b/c/d/boundary/boundary

**EDIT**

Gumbo thank you for your help

based on your rewrite rules i managed to create one.

Comment: Is the number of elements before boundary unlimited or at most n levels deep. If you know there are only n levels, writing n regexes would probably be much simpler.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try these rules:

```
RewriteRule ^/([^/]+)/(.+)/boundary/([^/]+)$ /$1_$2/boundary/$3 [N]
RewriteRule ^/([^/]+)/boundary/([^/]+)$ /boundary/$1/$2 [L]
```

Be careful with the first rules with the *N* flag causes an internal rewrite without incrementing the internal counter. So chances are that you have infinite recursion.

---

**Edit**    After you’ve changed your question:

```
RewriteCond $1 !=boundary
RewriteCond $2 !=boundary
RewriteRule ^/([^/]+)/([^/]+)(/.*)?$ /$1_$2$3 [N]
RewriteRule ^/([^/]+)/boundary(/.*)$ /boundary/$1$2 [L]
```

Comment: Sidenote: If they're in a per-directory (`.htaccess`) context, the `RewriteRule` test patterns should lose the initial forward slash. It worked perfectly on my test server using the example in the question, +1